# Showing dynamically generated ListView or Datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a double list I need to have shown sort of in a spreadsheet-like way, and I'm not sure what would be the best approach.

C#:

```
public class ViewModelClass
{
public List<ClassA> Data {get;set;}

//more code
}

public class ClassA
{
 public string ColumnName {get;set;}
public List<ClassB> Values {get;set;}
//more code
}

public class ClassB
{
public string DisplayValue {get;set;}
//more code
}
```

It should be shown as

| Row | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value1.1 | Value2.1 | Value3.1 |
| 2 |  | Value2.2 | Value3.1 |
| 3 |  | Value 2.3 |  |

from a dataset of

```
ViewModelClass vm;
...
vm.Data.Add(new ClassA { ColumnName="Item1", Values=new List<ClassB>() { new ClassB { DisplayValue="Item1.1" }}};
vm.Data.Add(new ClassA { ColumnName="Item2", Values=new List<ClassB>() { new ClassB { DisplayValue="Item2.1" },
new ClassB { DisplayValue="Item2.2" },new ClassB { DisplayValue="Item2.3" }}};
vm.Data.Add(new ClassA { ColumnName="Item3", Values=new List<ClassB>() { new ClassB { DisplayValue="Item3.1" },
new ClassB { DisplayValue="Item3.2" }}};
```

I found this thread, though it wasn't *quite* what I wanted: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/da5f36df-91e1-4a1a-9265-25c9a2b56414/binding-list-of-lists-to-datagrid?forum=wpf

My current code is

```
    var vm = DataContext as ViewModelClass;
    MyDataGrid.Columns.Clear();
    MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Row" });
    int count = vm.Data.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var col = new DataGridTextColumn { Header = vm.Data[i].ColumnName, Binding = new Binding($"Values") };
        MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
    }
```

Which gives me the right headers, but the rows are all "(Collection)"

Comment: Don't create columns this way. Consider to create a DataTable that you can directly assign as data source trip theItemsSource property. The DataGrid will generate the columns for you based on the DataTable.

Comment: But will that handle each column having its own list of (in my case) ClassB, with varying lengths?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. DataTable can have columns of any type. You specify the column type when you create it (via the constructor).

Comment: Well..if the type is a class, and you want to show a member from this class? I tried overriding ToString() for the class, but when the property value changes, the shown value isn't changed as ToString isn't called anew.
In my example with the ClassB class, I want DisplayValue shown (and it should change if DisplayValue changes)

Comment: DataTable orDataGrid are both not meant to accumulate different dates types to just show a single property of each. You create a DataTable as a new type. A data structure that is organized in rows and columns. You define a column of a type and then add rows to fill those columns. In you case you maybe want to add the value of a property of the ClassB. In your question you created a table to show what you are after.  A DataTable is a data structure that allows the exact data organization like a table, hence the name. You can the bind this DataTable to your DataGrid.

Comment: You must understand that a table is usually designed to present data in rows: every row is a data set. Your current structure is assuming that a dataset is expressed as a column. But a value for each column makes a row: instead of having ClassA to represent a complete column and associated values, you must implement ClassA as a row that has a single cell value for each column. It seems like your idea of how the table data structure works is not correct. You define columns and add rows to fill each column with a cell value.

Comment: A row is a dataset is an item (e.g. ClassA).  Such an item would therefore not have a column name. It's important to understand this. Then either convert ClassA so that it represents a row (DataGrid will generate columns that are named after the associated property) or create a DataTable (which of course is also row based).

Comment: I do want to show the value of a property in ClassB. The problem is, this property changes value, and I want to reflect that. I have overridden the ToString() function of ClassB as public override string ToString() => DisplayValue; That works fine when the new row is added, but if DisplayValue changes, it won't be shown until we're forced to redraw that field (ex by scrolling up and down in the list). I hoped to be able to set some sort of template for the field, where I could add a TextBlock binding to DisplayValue or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

To create a table like the one in your image you must redesign your class to represent a row based data structure.

If you don't want to use `DataTable` as data source for the `DataGrid`, then your class must be designed that it contains properties that each map to a column. The property's name is the column name by default. The class itself their represents a row.

The following example creates a type that has three columns named Item1...Item3:

```cs
class MyRowData : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
  // TODO:: Let all property setters raise the PropertyChanged event
  public string Item1 { get; set; }
  public string Item2 { get; set; }
  public string Item3 { get; set; }
}
```

This is your basic data structure.

To create the rows, you create the instances of `MyRowData` and add them to a collection that binds to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property:

```cs
// ItemsSource for the DataGrid 
public ObservableCollection<MyRowData> TableData { get; }

for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
  var newRow = new MyRowData 
  {
    Item1 = $"Value1.{i}",
    Item2 = $"Value2.{i}",
    Item3 = $"Value3.{i}"
  };

  this.TableData.Add(newRow);
}
```

To enable the `DataGrid` to update itself with modified data, your data model (in this case `MyRowData`) must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.